Is simultaing the synthetic control dependent variables with the same independent variables a valid approach?
im doing a synthetic control and i have some data limitations.
im making a synthetic control for a city in country A (treated unit) and for simulating the control group i have data for multiple citys of country B. however, i only have correlating data for the cities of country B at a national level. That is, im using a lot of "dependent variables" for the synth by using multiple cities of the Country B, but im only able to use the same "independent variables" at a national level for every country.
¿Is this a problem for synthetic control or is it a valid approach?
